# PDF reader that let me scroll down on a single page without page turn

Tags: pdf-viewer

I am searching for a pdf reader software that let me read the document using ”View single page” BUT not scrolling to next page if i scroll down (opposite of continuous scrolling). I want to scroll down / up my page in the pdf document to the end of the document without going to the next /previous page.

Instead, i want go to the next page by using a shortcut (next page) or pressing a button with the mouse.

But this is not the case, every time i scroll down i goes to the next page feeling that i lost the control, but i want to scroll down / up as much i want and still stays on the same page. More specificy, i want to scroll down on the scrolling wheel but stay on the same place: the end of the text at the bottom of the page.

And, lastly i want to read zoomed in (fit width works on my screen). Any pdf reader that can do this?

Tried Foxit and Sumatra but they didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You need Acrobat Reader.

If you set it for single page display, you can zoom as much as you want and the scroll (mouse wheel) only on that page. To change pages, you must click the next/previous page buttons or use the left/right arrow keys.

Refer to these images:

[image: Acrobat's Menu - Setting the Page View Mode]

[image: Acrobat's Page Navigation Controls]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried single page but it dosent seem to work :/. I am using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.
Tried different textbooks and most it dosent work for neither downarrows or mouse wheel, on one pdf with arrows i couldnt go to next page but the scrolling was to powerful and it goes to next page with very little mouse scrolling. (i am most interested in the scrolling --> no next page should work :)

Comment: I don't think you have the proper page view setting. Check out the images in my updated answer. I'm also using DC. Also, Acrobat uses whatever scroll speed you have set in your system.

Comment: Yes, i have does that settings and can easily scroll (unfortunately) between the pages no matter what pdf file i used.

Comment: I'd suggest that you re-install Acrobat. If you have those setting and it does not restrict the scrolling to within the page, then your install sounds broken. That's a basic functionality of Acrobat Reader.